# Как грамотно реализовать класс посредник(хелпер) загрузки файлов

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Решил сделать в asp .net core наподобии "тонкий контроллер", то есть чтобы сделать простоту загрузки, да и контроллерах не прописывать каждый раз одни и теже действия по загрузке картинки, и вынес это в другой класс. Не знаю правильно ли название, но назову "Helper".

Class ImageHelper:

```
 public ImageHelper(IFormFile file, string _pathName)
        {
            this._file = file;
            this.pathName = _pathName;
            this.fileName = Path.GetRandomFileName() + Path.GetExtension(_file.FileName);
        }
        public void Upload()
        {
            var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
                     "wwwroot/" + pathName) + $@"\{fileName}";

            using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(path))
            {
                _file.CopyTo(fs);
                fs.Flush();
            }

        }
        public string GetPath()
        {
            var PathDb = pathName + "/" + fileName;

            return PathDb;
        }
```

Controller (Post запрос):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrEdit(Service service, IFormFile file)
    {
         var image = new ImageHelper(file, "images/services");

           if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                            service.ImageUrl = image.GetPath(); //путь в бд записывается

                            _context.Update(service);

                             image.Upload(); //загрузка файла


                        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                    }

          return View(service);
        }
```

Это работает, но обязательно должен быть file получен (null не допускается).
Так вот, подскажите как можно это реализовать более грамотно. Чтобы в конструктор не передавать целый файл `new ImageHelper(file, ....` (в контроллере). То мне кажется неграмотный подход получается, так как обязательна должна быть загружена картинка, или в ином случае выдает ошибку:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Да и привязка сильная между классами получается.